# android - drawable background was wrong on resume

Tags: android, background, drawable, imagebutton

I have this drawable used for imageButton background

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="8px">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="3px"
                        android:left="3px"
                        android:right="3px"
                        android:top="3px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="2px"
                        android:left="2px"
                        android:right="2px"
                        android:top="2px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="2px"
                        android:left="2px"
                        android:right="2px"
                        android:top="2px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item >


        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="@color/colorFAB" />


        </shape>

    </item>


</layer-list>
```

and when this show for first time it works well, but onResume the activity this show wrong like this
**First time**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT5CC.png

**When reopen the activity**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP1qX.png

Please any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background programmatically in `onResume` of the ImageButton. You can do it via `setBackgroundResource()` and if it still doesn't work call `invalidate()`. Let me know if this helps or the solution you figured out if you've already gotten it.